# I have a site with a slideshow that is supposed to function by changing every ten second and able to manually function

Tags: javascript, html, css

My slideshow is supposed to change slides automatically every ten seconds and by manual input from the previous/next buttons and by the circle indicators as of now it is only changing from manual input and not automatically. Here is my html and my JS.

```
HTML
'''
<!--slidehow container-->
                    <div id="slideContainer">
                        <!--full-width images with number-->
                        <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">1 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/uber-scuba-gili-TucvB6VLPAU-unsplash.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">2 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/chrisS-seychelles.jpg">
                        </div><div class="mySlides">
                            <div class="slideNumber">3 / 3</div>
                            <img src="images/danielC-barca.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--next and previous button-->
                        <a class="previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <!--circle indicators-->
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                    </div>
'''

JS
'''
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
'''
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where's the code that supposed to automatically make the slide show run?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp (Check the section on automatic slideshows)

Comment: You have asked three questions related to your slideshow in the last two days. I would recommend following a tutorial instead.

Comment: I prefer community help. I appreciate it though!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTimeout(() => plusSlide(1), 10_000);` for the automatic update.
You will need a while loop like that:

```
while (slideIndex < totalSlidesLength) {
  setTimeout(() => plusSlide(1), 10_000);

}
```